# Xcode 9 Storyboards are not displaying properly

Tags: xcode9

On Xcode 9, all my storyboards seem to be displaying in blue outlines only. Doesn't seem to be a new feature....Anyone has the same issue?

[image]

Comment: Hey did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: same bug in xcode 9 gm

Comment: Hey did you ever solve this problem? Same issue in Xcode 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week of trying all the suggestions in the internet I found that Xcode 9 required some libraries in macOS High Sierra.

So install them and then it will work:

https://www.apple.com/lae/macos/high-sierra/

Hopefully it will help someone

Comment: Hi @Developer So far, This solution has solved your problem or not?

Comment: @vipulk617 Yes that what I said

Comment: It is not working on my system even after an update.

Answer (score 5):

I has this issue in two different storyboards, where I can see an error on the top which said:

> "An internal error occurred..."

In one of them I could solve the issue removing Derived Data following this steps on Xcode:

> Preferences > Locations > Derived Data > click the arrow to open in
>   Finder > Delete it

In the other one I wasn't able to solve it so I'm using Xcode 8 for that Storyboard (You can open both Xcode 8 and Xcode9b2 and code with them at the same time)

Comment: @kikettas I am facing same issue in Xcode 9. I have tried these solutions  and i have also restart my system two times but not able to solve this issue.

Comment: @vipulk617 same issue for me, Have any luck to solve this ?

Comment: Same problem, and this is not solving the issue. I hope somehow apple can solve this. :'(

Comment: It solved my problem, coming from a xcode 8 project. Deleted that folder, restarted xcode... and ... voilá, storyboard rendered correctly. Thanks

Comment: Fixed my issue. I closed xcode, deleted folder, reopened xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This recommendation might helpful for others who are not able to solve this issue.

This issue could occur If Xcode debugging tools are not installed properly,
While installing Xcode 9 from Mac OS 10.12.x. 
What I would recommend is you go to the below url, and install the additional tools(additional tools, comman line tools...) compatible with your OS version(v10.12 in this case).

> https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue by Hiding Rectangles Bounds

goto  Editor -> Canvas -> uncheck Show bounds Rectangles

[image]

> NOTE: check/uncheck twice if not done on first try

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue after upgrading to macOS High Sierra. Re-installing Xcode + command line tools did not help.

I changed this configuration in Xcode and it made the problem disappear: "Preferences" > "General" > "Locked Files" > "automatically unlock files".

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had both Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 open on same computer. Closing Xcode 8 and reopening Xcode 9 solved the problem.