# Xcode 9.2 Storyboard not displaying properly

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode9.2

This is in relation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532110/xcode-9-storyboards-are-not-displaying-properly) question, which didn't help me solve my problem, also I checked this `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` and got `IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch_*.crash` file, On checking it shows this[image: Storyboard Error]

At present my storyboard looks like this [image: Storyboard]

I tried deleting derived data, restarted Xcode, but didn't solve.

OS I use is macOS high Sierra

I have noted now whenever I switch from storyboard to another file or change device in storyboard, Xcode becomes (Not Responding), then I will have to Force Quit and restart Xcode again.

Edit : I use this code for status bar appearance

```
UIApplication.shared().statusBarStyle = .lightContent
UIApplication.shared() .isStatusBarHidden = false
```

And for @IBDesignable

```
extension UIView {
class func loadNib<T: UIView>(_ viewType: T.Type) -> T {
    let className = String.className(viewType)
    return Bundle(for: viewType).loadNibNamed(className, owner: nil, options: nil).first as! T
}

class func loadNib() -> Self {
    return loadNib(self)
}
}
@IBDesignable extension UIView {
@IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor? {
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue!.cgColor
    }
    get {
        if let color = layer.borderColor {
            return UIColor(cgColor:color)
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
@IBInspectable var borderWidth:CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
}
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        clipsToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your memory getting low. Your device specs please?

Comment: restart your xcode

Comment: @LalKrishna no Its not about memory, he has deleted `iOS DeviceSupport` and `iOS Device Logs` files. Thats why its showing debugger crash.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra How can i solve this as I am facing this from last 2 days and i have restarted rebooted multiple times.

Comment: I have faced the same issue, I answered your question below, follow the answer, it will lead your destination i hope.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra  I added a comment to your answer can you check and update me.

Comment: Are you either using `@ibdesignable` in your code or some form of status bar appearance changes. The stack hints at possible issues with that.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I have edited my question I am using above code for status bar and IBDesignable.

Comment: Does it make any difference to remove the status bar changes or IBDesignable tags was what I was wondering. The stack crash starts with a status bar customisation.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I can try removing this 2 codes, But this code is working perfectly in Xcode 8.3.2, I have 2 Xcode Installed in this 8.3.2 and 9.2.

Answer (score 2):

- Quit Xcode
- Delete derived data
- Start Xcode again
- Hopefully, this will solve your problem

Comment: I did this, it didn't work, then I restarted my computer and things were back to how they should be.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change device in storyboard, hope it will be shown again. I had faced the same issue before. I switched to another device and it was appeared as before, then i switch back to iPhone 8.

Your crash has generated due to, most probable you have deleted `iOS DeviceSupport` and `iOS Device Logs`, it will be fine, just close app and xcode, turn off the system completely and try again. Hope it may fix your crash.

[image]

Comment: I changed the device but still same, but I am noticing xcode goes not responding everytime i open storyboard or make change like this you mentioned above.

Comment: @niravdesai21does your xcode storyboard respond very slow or xcode become not responding everytime when you select the storyboard?

Comment: @ AbhishekMitra Yes

Comment: @niravdesai21 well then select storyboard and wait until it is open fully. then select iPhone X and wait again. it may takes 15 min more or less according to your system performance.

Comment: No bro still no help, i changed device from IPhone 8 Plus to IPhone 8. I also checked same on Xcode 8 storyboard opens fine But on Xcode 9.2 It doesn't.

Comment: Well, I can give you one suggestion, You must have xcode 8 in other machine and xcode 9.2 in other machine. then in scode 8 machine change your build version and zip that project, In that mean time xcode 9.2 machine, delete the whole project. from recycle bin too. now open that zip project in your 9.2's machine. and check. I did face that same, but i did above and it was worked. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161007/discussion-between-niravdesai21-and-abhishek-mitra).

Answer (score -1):

To remove the blue lines,

In Xcode, **Go to Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles**

This will hide the blue lines

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELPvK.png)

Comment: No help with this, already mentioned in my question a link which contains this solution.

Comment: have you tried to remove this file from project (remove references), then try to import it back

Answer (score -1):

Close and Restart your xcode it will work fine. if issue will be there then restart the mac.

**Note**
Always split your storyboard after max 10 controllers in it. Create new storyboards and link them

Comment: Read the question completely. He already tried that. "I tried deleting derived data, restarted Xcode, but didn't solve."